# "I study two hours daily" vs. "I study for two hours daily"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

1. I study two hours daily.
2. I study for two hours daily.

Is the preposition "for" correct here or not, and why? If both sentences are correct, what is the difference in grammatical usage?

Comment: Both are correct.  Because English.

Answer (score 1):

In some case we can omit the preposition without changing the meaning of the question. I often see many spoken dialogues omit that preposition and in some novels made by top notch writters.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work. You are better off, however, not ending your sentence with an adverb.

"I study daily for two hours."